# How to create unique identifier from string

Tags: oracle

I would like to generate unique itentifier from String (table id), which already unique. I have tried the following:

```
..
dbms_utility.get_hash_value(table1.id,1000,max_number) as unique_ID;
dbms_utility.get_hash_value(table2.id,1000,max_number) as unique_ID;
..
....
```

but hash value is not unique. What is the best way to get unique identifier from string?

Comment: Unique within what scope - the database, or externally unique across all systems, like a UUID?

Comment: the database :)

Comment: Why do you need such id if String is already unique? How do you want to use it?

Comment: ... or perhaps explain what you mean by "identifier". The unique string is already a "unique **identifier**" so perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: @mathguy the id is unique it its table but two tables can have the same id. with identifier I just mean a unique key.

Comment: The result of an hash function is not unique by definition, so you may need something different. What do you need this id for? for example, if you simply need to build an ID for your table, you may use a sequence.

Comment: did you try `rowid`